# Adding nodes to end of a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

The code I have is adding nodes to head but I want them added to tail. I tried pointing head to next node to null but it stops since the next node is null

```
if(head==NULL)
{
    head=node;
}
else
{
    node->next=head;
    node->prev=NULL;
    head->prev=node;
    head=node;
}
printf("The node is inserted to linked list succesfully. \n\n");
printMenu();
```

Comment: Remember to choose the answer that you found most helpful and accept it. It is quite important for the whole stack idea to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a pointer to your list's tail, and then adding an element may look like:

```
node -> next = NULL;
tail -> next = node;
node -> prev = tail;
tail = node;
```

Comment: yes i did that already but i didn't define tail as something different than head,so changing head's name with tail won't work

Comment: That's why you need to define `tail` as something different than `head` :-)

Comment: Your tail holds a pointer to the last element in the list, and not the first one (last means one that's next = NULL). Having head you can easily get your tail as well: `tail = head; while (tail->next != NULL) tail = tail->next;`. Note it is a good idea to store tail in a variable and not get it every time by iterating through the whole list (which is, of course, costly, compared to storing one variable). And by the way, it is quite common to store both Head and Tail pointers when operating on a two-way list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the end of the list first:

```
if(head==NULL)
{
    head=node;
}
else
{
  struct nodetype *p = head;
  while (p->next)
    p = p->next;
  p->next = node;
  node->prev = p;
}
```

Comment: ... or do what @Byakuya said

Comment: nodetype is the name of your struct (you didn't say what it was). I have amended it slightly to be correct C - using just the name of the type (instead of struct nodetype) is C++ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create new node
struct nodeType *newNode = (struct nodeType *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeType));

// Singly-linked list and new node is end of the list so the next pointer is NULL
newNode->next = NULL;

if(head==NULL){
    // If head is not assigned
    head = newNode;
}
else{
    // Assign the next pointer in the current node to the new node
    current->next = newNode;
}
// Update the current pointer to point to the newNode
current = newNode;
```

where head and current is,

```
struct nodeType *head, *current;
```

If the current pointer does not point to the end of the list you can iterate over the list to the end with the following line and then start appending to the linked-list:

```
for(current = head; current->next != NULL; current = current->next);
```